# Is there a way to fail an Azure DevOps pipeline build on WhiteSource report results?

Tags: security, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, whitesource-bolt

I have a step in my Azure DevOps build pipeline to generate a WhiteSource Bolt report

```
  - task: WhiteSource Bolt@20
displayName: "WhiteSource Bolt"
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to fail the build based on the report find vulnerabilities at a certain severity level?